# ClickOnce application that uses PostSharp 1.0 seems to require 1.5 assemblies in GAC

Tags: c#, clickonce, postsharp

I have installed PostSharp 1.5 on a machine that had 1.0 previously. Now, my application which links to 1.0SP1 assemblies has for some reason started requesting for 1.5 assemblies to be **in the GAC** on the client side. Does anyone know why this is? (I've asked on the PostSharp forum but received no reply.)

Answer (score 0):

well it could be a referencing problem.

if you reference a dll which references a non specific version another, which references a specific version of another.

You inherit the dependancy.
So in this case.

Your code -> Postsharp(v1.0) -> Postsharp.Laos(any version and gets 1.0) -> PostSharp.MSBuild.dll (v1.0)

You update postsharp

Your code -> Postsharp(v1.0) -> Postsharp.Laos(any version and gets 1.5) -> PostSharp.MSBuild.dll (v1.5)

*Note: the above is an example I'm not sure what order Postsharp references itself.*